# Evaluating simple summation

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, summation

can someone help with this summation. Seems simple, but... I have tried several options but cannot see the rule.

$\displaystyle 1-a+a^2-a^3+...a^{2008}-a^{2009}+\frac{a^{2010}}{1+a} {\text{ when}}\ {a = -4/5}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put $b=-a$. Equation becomes
$$\color{green}{1+b+b^2+b^3+\cdots+b^{2009}=\frac {b^{2010}-1}{b-1}=\frac{a^{2010}-1}{-a-1}}\\
\therefore \color{green}{1+b+b^2+b^3+\cdots+b^{2009}}+\frac{a^{2010}}{1+a}=\color{green}{\frac{a^{2010}-1}{-a-1}}+\frac{a^{2010}}{1+a}=\frac 1{a+1}=5$$

---

Alternatively, without using GP formulas:

$$\begin{align}S&=1-a+a^2-a^3+...a^{2008}-a^{2009}+\frac{a^{2010}}{1+a}\\\\
&=(1-a)(1+a^2+a^4+a^6+\cdots+a^{2008})+\frac{a^{2010}}{1+a}\\\\
(1+a)S&=(1+a)(1-a)(1+a^2+a^4+a^6+\cdots+a^{2008})+a^{2010}\\\\
&=(1-a^2)(1+a^2+a^4+a^6+\cdots+a^{2008})+a^{2010}\\\\
&=1\\
S&=\frac 1{1+a}\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  All but the last term forms a geometric series with ratio $-a$.  Sum the first $2009$ terms that way, then add in the last one.

Comment: Is there are any way to solve it without geometric series? We are talking about elementary school here.

Comment: @user120250 This is a geometric series; the formula given in kamil's answer _is_ the way to solve it.

Comment: @user120250:  you could punch each term into a calculator.  That is a lot of work.  The problem clearly expects you to sum the series, as that accounts for all $2009$ terms together.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
$$1-a+a^2+...-a^{2009}$$
$$=1+(-a)+(-a)^2+...+(-a)^{2009}$$
$$=\frac{(-a)^{2010}-1}{(-a)-1}=\frac{1-a^{2010}}{1+a}$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $S=1-a+a^2-...+a^{2008}-a^{2009}$.  To calculate $(1+a)S$,
$$\begin{array}{rcll}S=&1-&a+a^2-a^3+...-a^{2009}\\aS=&&a-a^2+a^3...+a^{2009}&-a^{2010}\\(1+a)S=&1&&-a^{2010}\end{array}$$
So $(1+a)$ times your full sum equals $1$.